# What can I do when getting "pd is not defined"? it seems to be combined with a dying kernel

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

Does anyone know the fix for this "pd is not defined"? it seems to be combined with a dying kernel. I'm using Jupyter Notebook.

```
I had started with these imports and didn't get an error message so I was assuming that pandas was imported successfully

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

Tried updating my Python version to 3.11

Comment: I don't think that error can happen if those two lines run without error. Can you check e.g. whether you saved the file, if you're running the file you think you are, things like that?

Comment: Show us the full code and the full error message.

Answer (score 0):

This should not be a python problem. Since `import pandas as pd` did not fail, you should try print out `print(pd)` and see where pandas is installed and maybe verify it is is properly installed. It should print out something like `lib/python3.x/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py'`.